# How to install android system images from a local image

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I have been trying to download a system image for AVD in android studio. in the sdk manager. But it is painfully slow for some reason. It shows in log that it is downloading from a specific link, so I went ahead and downloaded that via some other tool.

Now my question is, now that I have downloaded the zip. How do I make it so that the SDK manager will look up a local resource instead of the remote image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the extracted folder into ANDROID_SDK_HOME\system-image\android-25\ does the trick.